# Retrieving values of "checkboxgroup" in Ext.ux.grid.RowEditor in Extjs 3.2.1

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs3

I am trying to retrieve the checked values of  "checkboxgroup" in RowEditor grid in extjs. What I have done so far is I have created a checkboxgroup in one of my column of RowEditor like this

```
columns: [
{
             id: 'weekdays',
             header: 'Week Days',
             dataIndex: 'weekDays',
             width: 150,
             sortable: true,
             editor: {
                xtype: 'checkboxgroup',
                allowBlank: true,
                frame : true,
                vertical : true,
                columns: 2,
                items: [
                {boxLabel: 'Sunday', name: 'S', checked: true},
                {boxLabel: 'Monday', name: 'M', checked: true},
                {boxLabel: 'Tuesday', name: 'T', checked: true},
                {boxLabel: 'Wednesday', name: 'W', checked: true},
                {boxLabel: 'Thursday', name: 'T', checked: true},
                {boxLabel: 'Friday', name: 'F', checked: true},
                {boxLabel: 'Saturday', name: 'S', checked: true}
                ]
            }
        },{ ...........// rest other columns
```

I tried to retrieved the values using the getValue() method but it didn't worked. I tried

```
 var schdeditor = new Ext.ux.grid.RowEditor({
        saveText: 'Update',
        listeners: {
        afteredit: function(object, changes, r, rowIndex) {
        // Do custom things
        var cm = object.grid.colModel, 
        fields = object.items.items;
        var weeks = fields[0].getValue();
```

When I run this my browser just hangs and after some time I get an "Stack over flow error"